# Migrate Guest OS to Host OS

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-player

Is it possible to take a Guest OS running inside VMWare Player and create an ISO or some sort of installation utility that will allow me to install the Guest OS as the Host OS (replacing the current Host OS). Basically, I want to re-install an OS by first configuring the new OS inside a VM then moving it.

Comment: Why not just create a new partition, install the new OS on that, format the old partition, and merge the partitions together?

Comment: I've done that in the past, but not being able to access my current isntallation is a hassle.

Comment: Oh, good point.  This is certainly a very interesting idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research and found out this guy named Carlo Costanzo has done this.  He wrote two blog posts on it [here](http://www.vmwareinfo.com/2008/04/using-acronis-to-take-image-of-virtual.html) and [here](http://www.vmwareinfo.com/2008/04/v2p-part-ii.html).  Basically what you do is image the hard drive inside the VM, and then copy the image to the physical computer.  You also have to run a BartPE CD, because you'll probably run into driver issues.  I would recommend keeping your current install backed up somehow when you do this, just in case something goes wrong.